# Update model field names before saving

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using django `import_export` module to import excel files.

Some column names of the excel files are two or more words, which makes it difficult to use them as field names for a django model.

Is there a way to replace the spaces with underscores, for example `Column 1` with `Column_1` before saving?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: `.strip().replace(' ','_')`

Comment: This is what I have, but where am I supposed to add this?

Comment: [column_name](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_fields.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can **override a field and change its options, such as `column_name` - column name in excel file (i.e. with spaces)**, attribute = model field name.

[import-export doc](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#declaring-fields)

```
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    published_date = Field(attribute='published_date', column_name='published date')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

Comment: I get: Line number: 1 - "Column 'id' not found in dataset and import_id_fields does not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408741/django-import-export-process-data-before-saving-it-to-database

Comment: Do you upload file with ids? is id field set as one in ModelResource Meta: `class Meta: import_id_fields = ('published_date',)`?

Comment: No I dont have a column 'id' in the excel file and yes I tried using columns (that exist in the excel file) as the import_id_field, but always same error that he is looking for a column 'id' and cant find it. I dont know how this filter works, but I aussume that if the import_id_fields is set to smt else than 'id' he should look for that and not for 'id'.

Comment: Imho from brief github issues browse: `import_id_fields` accepts ModelResource field_names (like 'published_date'), or model field names, and gets its `column_name` value to check in file.
And this might have been fixed very recently - in latest [2.0 release](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/pull/996)